# Question regarding Radon-Nikodym derivative...

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure

The problems are as follows:

> (1) Let $X=[0,1]$ with Lebesuge measure and consider probability measures $\nu,\mu$ given by densities $f,g$ as follows:
>   $$\nu(E)=\int_{E} f\;dm\;\;and\;\;\mu(E)=\int_{E}g\;dm$$
>   $\forall E \subset [0,1]$ s.t $E$ measurable. Suppose $f(x),g(x)>0$ $\forall x\in [0,1]$. Is $\nu$ absolutely continuos w.rt to $\mu$? If it is, determine the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$. Is $\mu$ absolutely continuos w.r.t to $\nu$?
>
> (2) For a point $x$, define the Dirac measure $\delta_x$ to be
>   $$\delta_x=\chi_{A}$$
>   where $\chi_{A}$ is the indicator function over set A. For a fixed set $B$, define the Lebesgue measure restricted to $B$ by $m_B(A)=m(A \cap B)$. Let $\mu=\delta_1 + m_{[2,4]}$ and $\nu=\delta_0+m_{(1,2)}$. Show that $\nu$ is singular to $\mu$.

So, here's what I've done:

> 1) Since $f(x),g(x)>0$ $\forall x \in [0,1]$, it follows that
>   $$\nu(E),\mu(E)>0 \iff m(E)>0$$
>   and
>   $$\nu(E),\mu(E)=0 \iff m(E)=0$$
>   $$\implies \nu(E) << \mu(E)\;\;\;,\;\;\; \mu(E) << \nu(E)$$
>
> We wish to find $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$. Having $f=\frac{d\nu}{dm}$ and $g=\frac{d\mu}{dm}$, and then dividing $f$ by $g$, we obtain
>   $$\frac{\frac{d\nu}{dm}}{\frac{d\mu}{dm}}=\frac{f}{g}$$
>   $$\implies \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$
>   $\square$
>
> (2) Have
>   $$\mu=\delta_1 + m_{[2,4]}\;\;,\;\;\nu=\delta_0+m_{(1,2)}$$
>   $$\implies \mu(A)=\delta_1(A)+m_{[2,4]}(A)=\delta_1(A) + m(A\cap [2,4])$$
>   $$\nu(A)=\delta_0(A)+m_{(1,2)}(A)=\delta_0(A)+m(A\cap(1,2))$$
>   Notice that at each delta, we're dealing with a single point. In particular, the singletons $\{1\}=[1,1]$ and $\{0\}=[0,0]$. Thus,
>   $$\mu(A)=\delta_1(A) + m(A\cap [2,4])=\mu(A\cap([1,1]\cup [2,4]))$$
>   $$\nu(A)=\delta_0(A)+m(A\cap(1,2))=\nu(A\cap([0,0]\cup (1,2)))$$
>   Since $(A\cap([1,1]\cup [2,4])\cap(A\cap([0,0]\cup (1,2)))=\emptyset$, it follows that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are singular to one another.
>
> $\square$

Did I pull some nonsense? Radon and I have not been getting along so well, so I've had trouble properly wrapping my head around these findings. If I've gone down the wrong path, how I would I go about solving these problems?

Comment: Ha. Remus's class is fun, right? I have something similar in mind for the first question, but I think I understand it even less than you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First is correct: you can also write it shorter. Recall that two measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ are called equivalent if $\mu\ll \nu$ and $\nu\ll\mu$: this is denoted as $\mu\sim \nu$. This is an equivalence relation, and in particular it is transitive. Furthermore, $\mu\sim \nu$ iff $\frac{\mathrm d\nu}{\mathrm d\mu}$ exists and positive  ($\mu$-a.e.) or equivalently iff $\frac{\mathrm d\mu}{\mathrm d\nu}$ exists and positive  ($\nu$-a.e.).

1. Since $f,g>0$ we have $\mu\sim  m$ and $\nu\sim m$ hence by transitivity $\mu\sim \nu$. The ratio formula is also correct.
2. To show mutual singularity, we need to find a set $A$ such that $\mu(A^c) = 0$ and $\nu(A) = 0$: that is, $\mu$ is concetrated on $A$ and $\nu$ is on $A^c$. From the shape of $\mu$ it is clear, that $A = \{1\} \cup [2,4]$ is a good candidate, and you just need to check the latter two conditions to see that it works.

Your solution of 2. has certainly good thoughts, but is a bit confusing and unclear, I'd say. Especially the point where you express $\mu$ through $m$ and then again through $\mu$ itself.

Comment: I realized I made an error when writing up the end of my attempted proof for problem 2. Does this make things more clear and then steer towards the correct path? Or no? I wasn't quite sure how to proceed properly from
$$\mu(A)=\delta_1(A) + m(A\cap [2,4])$$
$$\nu(A)=\delta_0(A)+m(A\cap(1,2))$$

Comment: @user30625 you still have $\mu$ instead of $m$ in several places.

Comment: Okay I think I fixed them all now. Or are you suggesting a change as such as well:

$$\mu(A)=m(A\cap([1,1]\cup [2,4]))$$
$$\nu(A)=m(A\cap([0,0]\cup (1,2)))$$

Comment: @user30625: cool, so how would you approach this problem in case $\nu = \delta_0 + m_{[1,2]}$. In that case the intersection is non-empty; but would the answer be different?

Comment: We know that the measure of a singleton set is 0 so I don't *think* it would affect the answer, but I'm not sure. 

Sorry for such a late response!

Comment: @user30625: that's true, it does not affect the answer. Yet, your previous approach would not work here as the intersection is non-empty. Another question is: which *measure* of singleton set being zero is important here? What if $\mu = 0$ but $\nu >0 $ or vice-versa? To answer it, either read again my 2. in the answer, or write down here the definition of $\mu$ and $\nu$ being mutually singular.

Comment: I understand now how to think about mutual singularity now. Thank you, sir!